# Keep getting this error message trying to customize grub?

Tags: debian, grub2

I am trying to change my grub theme using [grub customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer) and using the theme [Vimix](https://github.com/vinceliuice/grub2-themes) and i keep getting this error. Note i have changed the image to a bitmap and i keep getting the same error except it says

> error: bitmap file `(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub/themes/grub-theme-vimix/background.bmp' is of unsupported format.

I am using debian and grub2. How can i fix this?

[image: Picture]

Comment: Resizing background.bmp should probably fix the problem. The resolution is probably to high.

Comment: It would help if you add / link `background.jpg` to your question. The image is likely to have the wrong format. AFAIK only PNG, JPEG and TGA are supported and JPEGs are restricted to 256 colors (see [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays)).

Comment: @Freddy Sorry this is the link https://github.com/vinceliuice/grub2-themes/blob/master/backgrounds/1080p/background-vimix.jpg

Comment: @DannysNotHere Hmm, your image works with grub2 2.02+dfsg1-20 (Debian Buster), tried it with resolution `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` (doesn't look so good when resized) and `GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080`. I added it with `GRUB_BACKGROUND=/path/to/image` to `/etc/default/grub` and ran `update-grub`. Also tried a [8bit PNG version](https://imgur.com/a/KaFE340) which also works.

Comment: @Freddy Thanks So much !